# Python multiple if statements in a single if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

How do I write the following in a single if statement:

```
if x != 5:
    if y < 4:
        statement
```

Comment: First you learn boolean logic.

Comment: I know it but my mind is so busy i couldn't find the solution to this simple question. sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if x != 5 and y < 4:
  statement
```